# Set the color of y axis coefficient in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is my Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create data
data = np.random.randn(200, 2)
data = data * 1e20
assert(data.ndim == 2)
assert(data.shape[1] == 2)
x = np.arange(data.shape[0])
fix, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x, data[:, 0], 'b')
for i in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    i.set_color('b')
ax1.set_ylabel('', color='b')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, data[:, 1], 'r')
for i in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    i.set_color('r')
plt.show()
```

I am trying to plot two curves sharing a same x axis on one plot. I also want to have different colors for the two y axes. I get the result:

[image: plot]

The thing is, on the left y axis, there is a coefficient "1e20" on the top. I want that to be colored blue too. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I am unable to replicate this problem (1e9 isn't even showing up) - could you provide some sample data for which it occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In matplotlib, the coefficient is referred to as the "offset text" for the axis that it is associated with. So you can access it by calling the `get_offset_text()` method on the appropriate axis object. You can then use various formatting methods. In this case, you'll want to call the `set_color()` method on the each of your y axes. You can accomplish this by adding the following two lines of code immediately before calling `plt.show()`:

```
ax1.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_color("blue")
ax2.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_color("red")
```